Install specific version of google chrome on Debian 12 docker image
I found this code snipet to install google chrome in a Debian 12 docker image:
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y wget 
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb || true
RUN apt install -y -f

It works fine for latest version.
However, I need to fix the google chrome version, but I could't find the list of older versions debian packages filenames...
For example, somethink like this:
https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_126.0_amd64.deb

Can someone tell me where do I find the .deb correct url to older versions ?
